# How to avoid Capoeira PCL strain

Tags: injury, capoeira

I'm quite fit and no stranger to sports, cardio or weight training but I'm not the most flexible.  So I gave [capoeira](/questions/tagged/capoeira) a little try, just the basics.  Ginga and some basic Esquiva.

The thing is I feel a little uncomfortable, a little strain in my PCL when just performing a Ginga and a little more during lower Esquiva.  I know this is probably due to bad technique and perhaps a little to do with my slightly lower flexibility but is there anything I can do to make sure my form isn't going to cause a PCL injury while I'm getting my form up to speed?
 Also, is this normal?

Comment: You mention that this happens during the Ginga and when you try Esquiva.  What particular movement is making you uncomfortable?  For example, is it when you put your leg back in the Ginga?  Is it when you put your hand on the floor for esquiva?

Comment: On the back-step of the ginga, the knee of my front leg.  Same for esquiva; step back on my left leg, right hand down, slight, uncomfortable right knee pressure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me preface by saying that without seeing your movement, it's hard to say what you're doing wrong.

So, assuming that you're doing the movements with a close approximation of "the right way", it probably boils down to flexibility.  I would just work on Ginga and maybe Esquiva for a while, throwing in some dynamic stretching kicks (try to kick your forehead with a straight leg).  Dynamic stretching is better for improving flexibility than static stretching.

I can't give you technical pointers without a better description (preferably video) of your technique.  But, generally speaking, when first starting out, people tend to lean back when their foot goes back in the Ginga.  The weight should stay forward.

Take it slowly!  Capoeira movements *do* rely on momentum, but you don't have to use speed where no speed is required.  I'm saying this, because if you're going too fast, you may not have time to recognize potential injury before it's already happened.

If you can clarify any of the above vagueness, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry, hard to clarify vagueness without any real understanding of the movements yet but I think you may have hit the nail on the head with the leaning back thing.  I was doing that, keeping the weight forward is helpful.  Stretching is probably the last little bit of strain I feel.

Comment: @RossDrew I'm glad I could help

Comment: +1 for "you don't have to use speed where no speed is required."